# Powershell in windows 8

Tags: powershell

I am trying to copy a folder structure to another location as backup. I would also like to exclude file types that are not interesting from the copy. I can do this using XCOPY in a BAT file, but would like to do it using PowerShell (just to try it).

**Test Folder Structure:**

```
c:\src  
c:\src\t1.txt  
c:\src\folder1  
c:\src\folder1\t2.txt
```

I have come up with this PowerShell script:

```
Copy-Item C:\src\ C:\dst\ -recurse
```

This gives the **expected output** if run once:

```
c:\dst  
c:\dst\t1.txt  
c:\dst\folder1  
c:\dst\folder1\t2.txt
```

If the same script is run twice the folder structure looks like this:

```
c:\dst  
c:\dst\t1.txt  
c:\dst\folder1  
c:\dst\folder1\t2.txt  
c:\dst\src  
c:\dst\src\t1.txt  
c:\dst\src\folder1  
c:\dst\src\folder1\t2.txt
```

Ie. it copies the src folder into the destination folder.
I would expect the script to behave the same every time it has been run, but I simply can not fathom what PowerShell is doing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
xcopy C:\src\*.* C:\dst\ /s /i
```

Comment: Yes this would be the commandline way to do it, but I was interested in using the Powershell....

Comment: powershell loves the command line - one does not replace the other - they are designed to complement each other and work together

Comment: Ahh, I actually thought that Powershell was a cmd replacement. But I might just use XCOPY from Powershell then. 
I have been using XCOPY in CMD but thought it was time to move on to Powershell now..

Comment: exactly, keep using the cmd line where appropriate

Answer (score 0):

Does this help?

`Copy-Item C:\src\* C:\dst\ -recurse`

Without the glob `*`, you're instructing powershell to copy the entire `src` directory into `dst` *recursively*, so it will also copy the `src` directory itself. Having the `*` should avoid this behaviour.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @JustinWood - why not? That should give the *expected output* as OP requests. Will add an explanation as to why. How does this differ from Jimbo's answer?

Comment: I ran across your answer in the low quality posts queue. Without the explanation, it should have been a comment. With the explanation, it is fine as an answer.

Comment: Unfortunately  `Copy-Item C:\src\* C:\dst\ -recurse` only copies the files and not the folder structure. The result is a dst folder with only the 2 files :(

Comment: @Rauhe Odd - works fine for me. Do you get any errors? What if you add the `-force` parameter?

Comment: I double checked, but it gave the same result (only files were copied). I then tried adding the `-force` parameter, but it did no difference. Thanks for the help anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

Someone filed a bug report here, but no resolution:

https://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/feedback/details/809855/subfolder-bug-with-command-copy-item-c-folder-c-folder2-recurse-when-done-more-times

You could try:

```
$testPath = Join-Path $dst (Split-Path $src -leaf);
if (-not (Test-Path $testPath)) { Copy-Item $src $dst -recurse }
```

or using brute force:

```
Copy-Item $src $dst -recurse -force
```

On my system, Win7/PowerShell 2 using only the `-recurse` parameter, the second run properly throws an error indicating the directory already exists. But FWIW the bug report above and a couple of other places I've seen on the Internet show the same behavior you're seeing with PowerShell 2 as well (creating the extra sub-directories).